# How to combine Jeditable and jQueryUI resizable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jeditable

I am trying to combine Jeditable with jQuery UI resizable. I get so close, except that it appears that Jeditable does something funny with the resizable functionality.

The problem with the code below is that there is an error (see below) calling the destroy function of resizable. I checked, the class is still there. At first I didn't include the destruction of resizable, but without destroying it and reinitializing it, after the first edit (or cancel) the resize no longer works. With the error, the cancel no longer works (i.e., it keeps the edits).

```
Error: cannot call methods on resizable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'
```

JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/y8Ayd/

HTML

```
<div class="box">Hello</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  background-color: #ccf;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

JS

```
$('.box').resizable();

$('.box').editable(
function (value, settings) {
    return (value);
}, 
{
    cancel: 'x',
    callback: function (value, settings) {
        $(this).resizable('destroy');
        $(this).resizable();
    },
    data: function (value, settings) {
        return value.replace('<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>', '');
    },
    event: 'dblclick',
    onreset: function (settings, original) {
        $(this).resizable('destroy');
        $(this).resizable();
    },
    submit: 'ok'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what it says in the Error message:
You are trying to call resizable() or resizable('destroy') prior to initializing the resizable.

However what you are trying to do is not working because
(jquery.jeditable.js)’s editable places inside the content the ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e etc. You realised this already because you where trying to remove that crap from the Value through value.replace('

A possibility would be to wrap a div around the editable and attach the resizable to that.

I made up a small sample for you:

or on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U4LUe/20/

HTML:

`<div id="EditBox1" class="editbox">Enter some Text...</div><br/>`

`<div id="EditBox2" class="editbox">Enter some Text in an Area...</div>`

CSS:

```
    .editboxwrapper {
      background-color: #ccf;
      width: 650px;
      min-height: 50px;
      padding: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .editbox {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    }
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    //on $(document).ready(function () {...});
    ResizableEditbox({
        selector: 'EditBox1',
        wrapperClassName: 'editboxwrapper' //the class of the wrapper (for css-style)
    });
    ResizableEditbox({
        selector: 'EditBox2',
        wrapperClassName: 'editboxwrapper' //the class of the wrapper (for css-style)
    });
});
function ResizableEditbox(args) {
    var me = this;
    this.args = args;
    this.wrapperName = args.selector + 'Wrapper';

    $('#' + args.selector).editable(
        function (value, settings) { //This fakes a real call to the server!
          return (value);
        }, {
        type: 'textarea',
        tooltip: 'Click to edit...',
        cancel: 'x',
        id: this,
        callback: function (value, settings) {
            me.InitResizable(me.wrapperName);
        },
        data: function (value, settings) {
            me.RemoveResizable(me.wrapperName);
            var retval = value;
            return retval;
        },
        event: 'click',
        onreset: function (settings, original) {
            //var class = $(this).className;
            me.InitResizable(me.wrapperName);
        },
        submit: 'ok',
        onsubmit: function (settings, td) {
            var value = td.textContent;
            if (value == "") {
                alert('Please enter a value');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
    this.CreateWrapper = function () {
        //create a div$('#' + args.selector).wrap("<div id='" + my.wrapperName + "' class='"     +     my.args.wrapperClassName + "'></div>");
        var wrapperDiv = $(document.createElement("div"));
        wrapperDiv.addClass(me.args.wrapperClassName);
        wrapperDiv[0].setAttribute("id", me.wrapperName);
        $('#' + args.selector).wrap(wrapperDiv[0].outerHTML); 
    };

    this.InitResizable = function(wrapperSelector) {
        var element = $('#' + wrapperSelector);
        if (element.length > 0) {
            if (!element.hasClass('ui-resizable-handle')) {
                element.resizable({
                    //Initialise
                });
            }
        }
    };
    this.RemoveResizable = function(wrapperSelector) {
        var element = $('#' + wrapperSelector);
        if (element.length > 0) {
            if (!element.hasClass('ui-resizable-handle')) {
                element.resizable('destroy');
            }
        }
    };
    me.CreateWrapper();
    me.InitResizable(me.wrapperName);
}
```